# Why labels/buttons are shown before viewController transition animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Trying here develop a side menu, but i'm facing a problem that i cannot figure out why is happening.

Here is a video sample to show what the problem is:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/i97iigus8gj2sl4/problem_side_menu.mov

When I press the menu button the labels appear first than the view controller, what I want is that the latest follow the transition animation.

I have a container view controller that manages all my views controllers.
Already did some research, but I really don't know which keywords use to find useful information.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

The animation suggests that you have drawn your buttons on wrong view. Make sure your side menu is owner of your button.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is fading the UILabels/UIButtons as the transition happens. So in your code that hides the side menu container, do the animations there.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                     animations:^
     {
         self.label.alpha = 0.0;
         self.button.alpha = 0.0;
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if (finished)
         {
             self.label.alpha = 1.0;
             self.button.alpha = 1.0;
         }
     }];
```